# Sanskrit vs. Modern Hindi

Tags: hindi

Hello I am about to start to learn Linguistics.There are atr two different sections i need to choose from that are quite different one teaches the Generative paradigm and the other teaches mainly fuctional theory. I don't have so much knowledge as of now to know exactly how do they differ. Any suggestions as to what to do?

Also, I am required to learn an old language and the possibilities are: Latin, Sanskrit and old Greek. I want to know Latin but I am a practical person and there is not a real value in Latin when considering money. But I wonder if knowing Sanskrit will help me learn modern Hindi?
What say you?
I thank everyone that will contribute.

Comment: I am no linguist, but as a matter of fact, I happen to have learnt Sanskrit in school. Many words in the Sanskrit carry over to modern Hindi and Bengali and some other Indian languages. And there are many similarities between Sanskrit and modern Hindi. So, if learning modern Hindi is your target at some point, Sanskrit can indeed help with that. Moreover if you use Devanagari script then even better, because you can write modern Hindi in Devanagari.

Comment: IMO, Sanskrit is so different from Hindi that very little carries over, though there is a fair load of Sanskrit learned vocabulary in Hindi (that's the source of beliefs of similarity). A Latin-Romance analogy is apt, and the differences in the languages are smaller. You already know the alphabet.

Comment: Thanks. So in conclusion you say there is no similarity apart from vocabulary (although it is something substantial if there are many words that share some similarity)

Comment: You didn't say where you were going to school, nor what languages you already have studied, nor why you want to study linguistics. If you are in India, learn Sanskrit, since you already know Devanagari and it has more relevance there than elsewhere. But you really must learn Greek and Latin, too. They're not that hard if you know English, and they're absolutely necessary to understand Indo-European linguistics. As for the theory choices, avoid making them if you can. Especially if you're in India.

Comment: Congratulations! If I were you, I'd choose functional linguistics (it describes natural languages more accurately than the generative theory)

Comment: I am going to a university. I know English, Arabic, Hebrew and I have interest in languages and the comparisons between languages is something I like to read about and atymology  fascinates me.  Currently, I am leaving in israhell but I plan to leave here and therefore I want to acquire skills that will help me to successfully immigration. Linguistics is nice but unless one is very brilliant he can't make a living from it. That is why I want to learn some important languages as i

Comment: Thanks Alex. It made more sense to me but as I mention my judgements is very superficial for the time being.

Comment: Thank you, @IloveIl. For general education and language learning facility, in your case I recommend you study at least one other Indo-European language, and at least one other non-Indo-European and non-Afro-Asiatic language (I recommend Indonesian, unless you want to learn a tone language, in which case I recommend Mandarin). The encyclopedia and Catford recommendations should take care of the rest. Use the glossary and bibliography in the encyclopedias. Oh, and read Trask's _Historical Linguistics_; it will put it all together and make it clear why you need phonetics.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: The four languages with the most native speakers are Mandarin, Spanish, English and Hindi.  Including non-natives, the four most-spoken languages are English, Mandarin, Spanish and Hindi.  Sanskrit will help you with Hindi; Latin (or Esperanto!) will help you with Spanish.  Cultural concerns aside, if I had to choose between Latin and Sanskrit, I'd pick Sanskrit because Latin has (among other things) collapsed the declension more.

Comment: Could you please explain your last sentence, friend?

Comment: I don't know about Greek or Sanskrit, but I have studied Latin, and although it is undoubtedly a very difficult language to learn, it helps a whole lot with English etymology. Plus, out of the three, it opens up doors to the most modern languages, not only romance, but most Germanic languages also have quite a few Latin loan words. (I was surprised myself to find out the common word for 'to write' in the scandivain languages was skrive (or skriva in Swedish) which is a Latin loan word, instead of cognates of 'write'.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular difference between the two modern theories except that they find different things to emphasize and different ways to relate them. Both can be confusing, if they don't happen to match up with the way you structure languages; but often they do, and that makes people enthusiastic. Taste as much as you can and see how much sense it makes to you.

Plus, it all depends on the professors. In grad school you don't take courses so much as you take professors. If you know who's teaching a course, sit in on another one they're teaching to see whether you can learn from them. If you find someone who impresses and educates you, take what they have and don't worry about theory.

As for the languages, that's for the historical part, not the grammatical part. Grammarians couldn't care less what language you take; it's the historical linguists who hafta do that. When I started grad school in linguistics (in 1960) we were required to take (out of a 3-term year) one term of Sanskrit, one term of Homeric Greek, and one term of comparative Indo-European. It was assumed we already knew Latin, which I luckily did.
You can't learn all that much in 3 months, but we got through Agni from the Rgveda and Nala.

Homeric Greek is the oldest and closest Greek to PIE. That, and the *Iliad* and the *Odyssey*, are the only things it has going for it.

Latin you can pick up whenever you get around to learning some Romance language -- if you know historical phonology (though, granted, it would be easier the other way round) -- because almost all the steps between Latin and its primary daughters are well-known. Plus, Latin itself is only good for inscriptions on fountains and double entendres.

I'd recommend Sanskrit, if that's your only other choice. It certainly will help you read Hindi, though the spoken language is quite different from whatever you might read in Sanskrit (and they won't teach you how to pronounce it well, either, because it's strictly a reading language).

Too bad there isn't another Afro-Asiatic language on the menu; if you already know two of them, you might get a kick out of Hausa.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the second question of yours ("Sanskrit vs. Modern Hindi", as described by you).

You mentioned that the primary goal is to learn an old language, with only three choices (perhaps restricted by course availability), and you want to choose the one which helps you with your secondary goal of learning modern Hindi.

So, I suggest you go ahead with Sanskrit. It will help in your learning of Hindi in the following ways:

1. Grammar: Sanskrit and Hindi are quite similar in existence and rules of features like *sandhi* (joining, means modification of adjacent sounds for ease of pronunciation, or space-saving), *samaasa* (compound words), prefixes, suffixes etc. These will help in reading and writing Hindi, especially if you learn Sanskrit in the Devanagiri script.
2. Vocabulary: Hindi has words derived from many languages, but most of them are from Sanskrit and Prakrit, a derivative of Sanskrit. I am unable to find a number, but I believe Sanskrit loanwords form the largest [section of Hindi vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi#Vocabulary).

However, an important part of learning Sanskrit is *shabdroop* (noun/adjective inflections with formative particles as suffixes) and *dhaaturoop* (verb inflections). Every *shabd* or root word is not used directly but modified as per ending sound (~15 types) of that root word, its gender (3), cases (8), singular/dual/plural(3). So, a whole lot of tables of *shabdroop* are to be learned (approximately 15×3×8×3 ≈ 1080 different suffixes!), and similarly for *dhaturoop*. This memorization of inflections is not at all necessary for learning Hindi noun forms (which is done by use of helping words that vary only by 8 cases and sometimes gender, used in a particular word-order). Thus, someone intending to primarily learn Hindi would rather learn it directly than going through the Sanskrit route.

Comment: THank you very much my friend. I appreciate the detailed answer. Latin sounds also food, no?

Comment: I haven't studied Latin at all, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you with it.